# C*-Algebras: Continuity of the absolute value?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, absolute-value, c-star-algebras

In a $C^*$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$, it is possible to define the absolute value $|X| \in \mathcal{A}$ of an element $X \in \mathcal{A}$ via

$|X| := \sqrt{X^*X}$,

where the square root of a positive element $Y=X^*X$ is defined to be the unique positive $Z$ such that $Y=Z^*Z$. When restricting the mapping to the real subspace of self-adjoint elements, this formula simplifies to

$|X| = \sqrt{X^2}$.

Is $X \mapsto |X|$ (or at least its restriction to the subspace of self-adjoints) continuous with respect to the norm topology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following result should do the job, I think. It is Lemma 1.2.5 in Rordam's *Introduction to K-theory for $C^{\ast}$-algebras*

> Let $K$ be a non-empty compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and $f:K\to \mathbb{C}$ be a continuous function. Let $A$ be a unital $C^{\ast}$-algebra, and let $\Omega_K$ be the set of all self-adjoint elements in $A$ with spectrum contained in $K$. The induced function
>   $$
> f:\Omega_K\to A \text{ given by } a\mapsto f(a)
> $$
>   is continuous.

Answer (score 3):

You can write your map $|\cdot|$ as a composition:

$$|\cdot|=\sqrt{\phantom{a}}\circ\mu \circ(\mathrm{id}^*,\mathrm{id})\circ\Delta$$
where $\Delta:\mathcal A\to\mathcal A\times \mathcal A$, $x\mapsto(x,x)$, is the diagonal map, $\mathrm{id^*}$ is the involution, $\mu(x,y)=x\cdot y$ the multiplication and $\sqrt{\phantom{a}}:P\to P$ is the square root, defined on the cone of positive elements.

All maps are continuous, so $|\cdot|$ is continuous. To see why the root is continuous look at eg [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1633504/is-the-square-root-function-norm-continuous).

Comment: How do you know that the spectrum of every element in the cone is contained in a unique compact subset

Comment: The subset is not unique, and is not a subset so that the spectrum of every positive element lies in this. The proof uses instead that any convergent sequence in $P$ has bounded spectrum. The spectrum of an hermitian operator $x$ is a subset of $[-\|x\|,\|x\|]$. If the operator is positive then the lower bound can be taken $0$. If you have a norm convergent sequence $x_n$ then this sequence is necessarily norm-bounded. So $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\sigma(x_n)\subseteq [0,\text{Bound}]$.

Comment: Yes, of course and nice one +1

Comment: Thank you! The link you provided seems to answer my question for any function constructed using continuous functional calculus - the sketch of proof given there seems to be a blueprint for the more general result cited by Mr. Vaidyanathan.