# Positive elements in $M_{n}(C(X))$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space and $C(X)$ the $C^{*}$-algebra of continuous functions on $X$. Then $M_{n}(C(X))$ is a $C^{*}$-algebra which can be viewed as $M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$-valued functions on $X$. If $F\in M_{n}(C(X))$ is positive then $F=GG^{*}$ for some $G\in M_{n}(C(X))$ and it follows easily that $F(x)\geq 0$ for each $x\in X$. How do I show that the converse is true, i.e., if $F(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in X$, then $F\geq 0$?

Comment: There is a canonical isomorphism $M_n(C(X))= C(X,M_n(\mathbb{C}))$. This preserves positivity, and your result follows immediately from this.

Comment: @J.DeRo How can I convince myself that the positive elements of $C(X,M_{n}(\mathbb{C}))$ have the right form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is answered by the following fact:

> Let $A$ be a unital $C^*$-algebra and $X$ a compact Hausdorff space.
> Assume that $F \in C(X,A)$ satisfies $F(x)\in A^+$ for all $x\in X$,
> then $F\in C(X,A)^+$.

**Proof 1**: Clearly $F$ is self-adjoint, so it suffices to show that the spectrum of $F$ is positive. Note that $F-\lambda1$ is invertible in $C(X,A)$ if and only if $F(x)-\lambda 1_A$ is invertible in $A$ for every $x\in X$. In other words,
$$\sigma_{C(X,A)}(F) = \bigcup_{x\in X} \sigma_A(F(x)).$$
By assumption $\sigma_A(F(x))\subseteq [0, \infty[$ for all $x\in X$, so that $\sigma_{C(X,A)}(F)\subseteq [0, \infty[$ as well.

**Proof 2**: Define $G: X \to A: x \mapsto F(x)^{1/2}$. Then $G$ is continuous and $F= G^*G\ge 0.$

Comment: Proof 2 convinces me, but the problem I had when I tried the proof 1 route is showing that $\lambda\in\sigma_{\mathcal{C}(X,A)}(F)$ implies $\lambda\in\cup\sigma_{A}(F(x))$. Suppose $F-\lambda I$ doesn't have a two-sided inverse. I don't see why that implies $F(x)-\lambda I$ doesn't have a two-sided inverse for some $x$. If $G(x)$ is a two-sided inverse for $F(x)-\lambda I$ for every $x$, then we don't necessarily have a contradiction since we don't know that $G$ is continuous.

Comment: @SihOASHoihd You can prove the following: If $F(x)$ is invertible in $A$ for every $x\in A$, say with inverse $G(x):= F(x)^{-1}$, then $G$ is continuous. Indeed, the map $G$ is the composition $X \stackrel{F}\to \operatorname{Inv}(A) \stackrel{inv}\to A$ and the inversion map $\operatorname{inv}: \operatorname{inv}(A)\to A$ is continuous for any Banach algebra. Therefore, $G$ is continuous as a composition of continuous functions. Does this solve your concern?

Comment: Actually, I have a question about Proof 2 also, namely, why is $G$ continuous? Since we don't know that $F$ is positive, we don't a priori know that $G=\sqrt{F}$.

Comment: @SihOASHoihd Same argument, taking square roots is a norm-continuous operation, so $G$ is continuous as a composition of continuous functions. See e.g. here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1633504/is-the-square-root-function-norm-continuous